# How should I merge my local git branch in IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Assume that I have IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, we use git. I have local/remote branch1, my colleague has local/remote branch2. I would like to add changes from branch2 to branch1 using IDEA. What steps should I do?

The 1st way: I make local branch2, update it from the remote branch2. Then I switch to local branch1 and merge with the local branch2.

The 2nd way. I am at local branch1. I directly merge with the remote branch2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want the commit history to look.

If you want all of the changes from branch1 to appear as if they're combining with branch2, then you would merge branch1 into branch2.  If you want it the other way, then you would do the opposite.

You would only be merging into one branch in this manner.  Provided there aren't any conflicts, the merge will be straightforward.

Comment: No, I mean this: merge local branch1 with updated local branch2 or directly merge local branch1 with remote branch2.